# Italic not working when using underscore

Tags: bug, markdown

See this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15223503/475125

The format being used:

*note: file_get_contents required [`link`](http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php).*

Interestingly, this works fine:

*note: file required [`link`](http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php).*

which makes it seem as if anything with an `_` in it will break the formatting for italic.

Comment: Well. Isn't `_` an alias for `*` in markdown? =)

Comment: Yes `_` will break italics, because `_` is also used for italics along with the single `*`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape the underscores in that sentence, they confuse the markup:

```
*note: file\_get\_contents required [`allow_url_fopen`][4].*
```

renders as

*note: file_get_contents required [`allow_url_fopen`](http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php).*

Both `_` and `*` are used for markdown italics and bold.

Comment: My mistake. I didn't realise _ was also used for markdown.